# How to shift columns in pandas df left based on value in another column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas df like shown in the first image and:

- I need to shift the columns between “Col_1” and “Col_10” left in each row based on the value in the “Shift” column. The end result should look like what’s shown in the second image.
- Also, if there’s a way to fill in the now empty cells with the highest value out of the previous three numbers in each row (in this case always 10), how would I do that?

[image]

[image]

Comment: On SO you have to post your own code attempt, explain where you got stuck. It's not allowed to just post a spec and ask people to give you code.

Comment: Sorry about that, i’m a new contributor!

Answer (score -1):

Use `shift` on each rows:

```
df.iloc[:, 1:] = df.apply(lambda x: x.iloc[1:].shift(-x.loc['Shift']),
                          axis=1, result_type='expand')
print(df)

# Output
   Shift  Col_1  Col_2  Col_3  Col_4  Col_5  Col_6  Col_7  Col_8  Col_9  Col_10
0      5    6.0    7.0    8.0    9.0   10.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
1      3    4.0    5.0    6.0    7.0    8.0    9.0   10.0    NaN    NaN     NaN
2      2    3.0    4.0    5.0    6.0    7.0    8.0    9.0   10.0    NaN     NaN
3      4    5.0    6.0    7.0    8.0    9.0   10.0    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
4      1    2.0    3.0    4.0    5.0    6.0    7.0    8.0    9.0   10.0     NaN
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!